# typescript shorthand null or undefined to number

Tags: angular, typescript

product can be undefined or null additionally price within product can be undefined or null

so

```
  getClasses(key: number): string {
            let product = this.model.getProduct(key);
            return `pa-1 ${product.price < 50 ? "bg-info" : "bg-warning"}`;
            }
```

results in

> TS Object is possibly undefined

and

```
  getClasses(key: number): string {
        let product = this.model.getProduct(key);
            return `pa-1 ${product && product.price ? product.price :0 < 50 ? "bg-info" : "bg-warning"}`;
        }
    }
```

works ok.

I was just wondering if there is a shorthand for `product && product.price ? product.price :0`  it just seems fairly verbose.  something like `product?.price?||0`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Optional chaining has been implemented in TypeScript 3.7.

The syntax is based on the ECMAScript specification for the same feature:

```
const num = product?.price ?? 0;
```

Comment: Now available, Typescript 3.7. And it'd be like this: `product?.price ?? 0` — where `??` understands that things like `0` and `''` (empty string) are values, not undefined / null.